# Distribute remote_api_shell .py requests among many instances

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using `remote_api_shell.py` to query a large data set on my App Engine datastore. I'm using threads to parallelize the requests, but after looking at the App Engine dashboard, I see that only one instance of the version I'm addressing is being (over)loaded, while the other instance is almost idle.

Can I force requests distribution?

Comment: I'm intrigued as to what you are doing. remote_api_shell is really nothing more than a debugging tool, and shouldn't be used for any heavy-duty work.

Comment: I need to import ~20K users in to the DB while querying two other db's for each user (long story). remote_api_shell is the best tool (I've found) for it because I can alter and run the code locally.

Comment: You can always launch tasks from the remote_api, I find that is the most efficient way for these sorts of things.  Also nothing stops you from splitting your workload into multiple remote_api sessions and each one then has a unique connection.  This is more likely to get you seperate instance, whereas threads will share the same connection which will all go to a single instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a module within your app engine app, you can control a lot of factors about how that module scales up and the nature of its instances -- see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/ .

Then, you can address requests to specific modules, or even specific versions and instance of a module, as shown at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/routing -- all the way down to the granularity of the first example that page gives,

```
https://instance-dot-version-dot-module-dot-app-id.appspot.com
```

Comment: @MeLight, if you structure your GAE App with modules, your command lines can achieve distribution by using different URLs of the general form shown above.  Using modules is easy -- see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/converting